# Not being able to display data table using Plotly Dash code for larger file size

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I am using the following code (from Plotly Dash documentation)to display a data table after uploading an csv/xlsx file into the Dash app.

```
import base64
import datetime
import io

from jupyter_dash import JupyterDash

import dash
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State
from dash import dcc, html, dash_table

import pandas as pd

external_stylesheets = ['https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css']

app = JupyterDash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)

app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Upload(
        id='upload-data',
        children=html.Div([
            'Drag and Drop or ',
            html.A('Select Files')
        ]),
        style={
            'width': '100%',
            'height': '60px',
            'lineHeight': '60px',
            'borderWidth': '1px',
            'borderStyle': 'dashed',
            'borderRadius': '5px',
            'textAlign': 'center',
            'margin': '10px'
        },
        # Allow multiple files to be uploaded
        multiple=True
    ),
    html.Div(id='output-data-upload'),
])

def parse_contents(contents, filename, date):
    content_type, content_string = contents.split(',')

    decoded = base64.b64decode(content_string)
    try:
        if 'csv' in filename:
            # Assume that the user uploaded a CSV file
            df = pd.read_csv(
                io.StringIO(decoded.decode('utf-8')))
        elif 'xls' in filename:
            # Assume that the user uploaded an excel file
            df = pd.read_excel(io.BytesIO(decoded))
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        return html.Div([
            'There was an error processing this file.'
        ])

    return html.Div([
        html.H5(filename),
        html.H6(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(date)),

        dash_table.DataTable(
            df.to_dict('records'),
            [{'name': i, 'id': i} for i in df.columns],
            page_size =15
        ),

        
        
        html.Hr(),  # horizontal line

        # For debugging, display the raw contents provided by the web browser
        html.Div('Raw Content'),
        html.Pre(contents[0:200] + '...', style={
            'whiteSpace': 'pre-wrap',
            'wordBreak': 'break-all'
        })
    ])

@app.callback(Output('output-data-upload', 'children'),
              Input('upload-data', 'contents'),
              State('upload-data', 'filename'),
              State('upload-data', 'last_modified'))
def update_output(list_of_contents, list_of_names, list_of_dates):
    if list_of_contents is not None:
        children = [
            parse_contents(c, n, d) for c, n, d in
            zip(list_of_contents, list_of_names, list_of_dates)]
        return children



app.run_server(mode='external')
```

Strangely, for files with size (1mb - 2mb) I am being able to display the file but for a file of size 14mb (approx) I am not being able to do the same and it is just looking like this -

[image]

I have tried using the max_size property setting it to -1(infinite size) as well but it doesn't solve the problem. Is there any way to do the same using dash_uploader?

Comment: Are you running out of resources? CPU/mem? Maybe it's just taking a long time. 14MB is a pretty large table.

Comment: I don't think that's the case here

Comment: Do you get any console errors when trying to upload that file? JS or Python console.

Comment: No error whatsoever. As an exercise one can run this code and upload any file of size 15mb and see if they are getting the datatable. You will surely get it for smaller file sizes. Just to add, I am using Jupyter Notebook if that is at all relevant.

Comment: Also, dash_uploader seems like a good alternative to this but I don't know how to access the file uploaded using dash_uploader. (Documentation : https://github.com/np-8/dash-uploader/blob/dev/docs/dash-uploader.md#ducallback)